# How do you run a Swift Combine Publisher for a certain amount of time?

Tags: swift, combine, publisher

I have a publisher when the sink, scans for a list of wifi.  I only want to scan for about 10 seconds and stop.

Is there a way to do this within the publisher chain of calls?

Comment: How often do you want to scan? Do you want to stop scanning after a time limit (e.g. 10 seconds), or after a certain number of scans (e.g. after 10 scans, where each is spaced apart by 1s)?

Comment: And is there some trigger that should start a rescan?

Comment: the scan is called once with data coming back every second.  I want to stop after 10 seconds. @Alexander

Comment: Are you using combine to trigger the each scan?

Comment: @Alexander.   No.  ie wifiListPublisher.sink...  wifiListPublisher is a custom publisher that makes a call and outputs every second with wifi ssid.

Comment: I think writing a version of the Combine Timer without repeating and zip it with another publisher is one way to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This operator will do the trick.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation
import Combine

let page = PlaygroundPage.current
page.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

extension Publisher {
    func stopAfter<S>(_ interval: S.SchedulerTimeType.Stride, tolerance: S.SchedulerTimeType.Stride? = nil, scheduler: S, options: S.SchedulerOptions? = nil) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> where S: Scheduler {
        prefix(untilOutputFrom: Just(()).delay(for: interval, tolerance: tolerance, scheduler: scheduler, options: nil))
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

let source = Timer.publish(every: 1, tolerance: nil, on: RunLoop.main, in: .default, options: nil)
    .autoconnect()
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()

let cancellable = source
    .stopAfter(10, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink(receiveValue: { print($0) })
```

Comment: The timeout publisher can be simplified to something like `Just(1).delay(for: 10, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)`

Comment: @Cristik Thanks for the improvement. I also wrapped the function in a new operator like you did.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [timeout()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/timeout(_:scheduler:options:customerror:)) operator:

> Terminates publishing if the upstream publisher exceeds the specified time interval without producing an element.

```swift
wifiScannerPublisher
    .timeout(.seconds(waitTime), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main, options: nil, customError:nil)
    .sink(
        receiveCompletion: { print("completion: \($0), at: \(Date())") },
        receiveValue: { print("wifi: \($0)") }
     )
```

---

If, however your publisher keeps regularly emitting events, and you just want to stop it after an amount of time passes, then [Daniel's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69762412/1974224) answer is probably the way to go.

Nonetheless, I'll add a solution on my own, via a `Publisher` extension that uses `timeout()` and `scan()`:

```swift
extension Publisher {
    func stopAfter(_ interval: TimeInterval) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> {
        self
            .timeout(.seconds(interval), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .scan((Date()+interval, nil)) { ($0.0, $1) }
            .prefix(while: { Date() < $0.0 })
            .map { $0.1! }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

The above publisher will carry the timeout date, and once that date is reached, it will stop. The `map` is needed to discard the extra `Date` carried along the items.

Usage:

```swift
wifiListPublisher.stopAfter(10)
    .sink(...)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for my scenario as I need to collect the stream of output for the amount of time without erroring out.

Comment: The output values should already be sent by the time the error comes. But if you don't want an error you can `catch` the publisher. Depends on how your wifi publisher emits values. @Unikorn

Comment: Timeout doesn't stop if you keep receiving values as in the case of wifi scan.   From apple doc: Terminates publishing if the upstream publisher exceeds the specified time interval without producing an element.

Comment: @Unikorn, so you want for the publisher to end after 10 seconds, regardless if new wifis keep being discovered?

Comment: I want the publisher to complete in 10 seconds.   The publisher will keep publishing wifi list every second indefinitely until request to stop.  The prefix(untilOutputFrom:) works well in this situation.

Comment: @Unikorn yeah, in that case Daniel's solution is the way to go.